# dlclick no Transformer me da um erro de pilha: Maximum call stack size exceed

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um site com `konva.js`, nele é possível redimensionar os "rects" da tela. No entanto, quando eu clico em dblclick no transformador recebo o erro:

```
Uncaught RangeError: tamanho máximo da pilha de chamadas excedido
```

Isso bloqueia completamente a tela e me impede de arrastar, redimensionar o que está nela.

basicamente sem `if (true) {return;}` o transformador não comete erro, mas nesse caso seria necessário fazer algumas verificações com o transformador. O erro ocorre apenas com dblclick em um dos vértices do transformador.

Gostaria de saber se é possível resolver ou devo verificar em outro local.

Já tentei colocar o return new / old BoundBox, mas o erro continua.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<!-- USE DEVELOPMENT VERSION -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@3.2.4/konva.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Konva Select and Transform Demo</title>
<style>
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
 var width = window.innerWidth;
 var height = window.innerHeight;

 var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height
 });

 var layer = new Konva.Layer();
 stage.add(layer);

 var rect1 = new Konva.Rect({
  x: 60,
  y: 60,
  width: 100,
  height: 90,
  fill: 'red',
  name: 'rect',
  draggable: true
 });
 layer.add(rect1);

 var rect2 = new Konva.Rect({
  x: 250,
  y: 100,
  width: 150,
  height: 90,
  fill: 'green',
  name: 'rect',
  draggable: true
 });
 layer.add(rect2);
 layer.draw();

 stage.on('click tap', function (e) {
  // if click on empty area - remove all transformers
  if (e.target === stage) {
   stage.find('Transformer').destroy();
   layer.draw();
   return;
  }
  // do nothing if clicked NOT on our rectangles
  if (!e.target.hasName('rect')) {
   return;
  }
  // remove old transformers
  // TODO: we can skip it if current rect is already selected
  stage.find('Transformer').destroy();

  // create new transformer
  var tr = new Konva.Transformer({
   isTransformer: true,
   rotateEnabled: false,
   ignoreStroke: true,
   boundBoxFunc: function (oldBoundBox, newBoundBox) {
    if (true){
     return ;
    }
    return newBoundBox;
   }
  });
  layer.add(tr);
  tr.attachTo(e.target);
  layer.draw();
 });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja bem, quando você utiliza uma estrutura que demanda um controle condicional booleano e você define o controle para 100% das vezes ser true(que é o caso do seu if (true) { // ... }) você não está criando uma condicional, mas sim uma estrutura absoluta, em 100% das vezes o true será passado e o if vai ser executado rodando o "return", o "return" fará com que a função de boundBoxFunc seja finalizada e o seu parâmetro new/old boundBox nunca seja retornado como resultado.

Acredito que essa falha na lógica resulte no bloqueio de funcionamento pois ao disparar o evento essa função será chamada e como o retorno dela foi undefined a biblioteca vai tentar chama-la novamente até obter um valor válido para prosseguir, resultando no erro "maximum call stack size exceed" pois perceba que isso vai gerar uma sequência infinita de chamadas sem propósito algum e para evitar um loop infinito e um down de sua máquina o motor se encarrega de finalizar essa falha.

Comment: Bom, acredito que meu exemplo tenha sido falho. Não passo true como algo absoluto mas sim como uma variável, no caso estaria verificando se determinada condição seria ou não verdadeira, a verificação funciona o único problema é caso o usuário dê dblclick no transformador :(

Comment: Seria uma estrutura como `if (foo = true){return}`